# Ruby on Rails | return the parent of a model for a rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently creating a Ruby on Rails REST APi with a few relationships in place.
fairly new to ruby, not my first programming language tho.
For the future, what are the best resources to research things like this.

My routes.rb:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users 
      resources :timelines do
        resources :timelineusers 
        resources :timelinepost do
          resources :timelinepostfiles 
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now regardign my question. From a child model, after i created the parent, in this example timeline, when i create the child (timelineusers) how would i go on to receive the parent from the child.
I found out it's possible to define a private method to find the parent by the user id, but is this even a viable way to solve this problem

```
def findparent
        @parent = TimeLineUser.find(params[:id]).parent.id
    end
```

even if this would word, how would i define a new HTTP Path to access said findparent function.
Maybe you can help me out

Edited because my formatting was off

Comment: You mean `@parent = TimeLine.find(params[:timeline_id])`? The path to timelineusers in this case is "/api/v1/timelines/:timeline_id/timelineusers/:timelineuser_id" so you can use the route parameter for `:timeline_id` to find the `TimeLine`. [Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: I just now realise my post was pretty dumb :-9

Comment: Btw. even the official Rails Guides suggest not nesting routes that deeply, see [Limits to Nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) and the following [Shallow Nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) paragraph.